# base64 encoding with ios8/ios9 api without line length limit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, base64, ios9

How to base64 encode string with ios8 and ios9 api without line length limit.

I'm preparing some custom basic authentication and I need to encode credentials according to standard which means:

The resulting string is then encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line

In old ios7 there was a method: NSData base64Encoding but now is deprecated and instead of it I have:

```
- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithOptions:
(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)options NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
```

and the options are:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSDataBase64EncodingOptions) {
// Use zero or one of the following to control the maximum line length after which a line ending is inserted. No line endings are inserted by default.
NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength = 1UL << 0,
NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength = 1UL << 1,

// Use zero or more of the following to specify which kind of line ending is inserted. The default line ending is CR LF.
NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn = 1UL << 4,
NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed = 1UL << 5,

} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
```

So I can choose line length 64 or 76. The base64 encoding for basic authentication don't have line length limit so how can I approach to this.

Comment: Could you not just remove any new lines after you've got the string? Use `NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn` and then replace \n with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't choose any options, [line endings are not added](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/base64EncodedStringWithOptions:).

```
[myData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]; // One long string
```